# Срабатывание transition при загрузке страницы

Tags: html, css

Возможно где-то это проблема и решалась, но я не нашел. Когда страница загружается происходит так что по неизвестной мне причине срабатывает :hover эффект. Почему так я не знаю. Можно проверить то о чем я говорю

```css
.main{
background:green;
width:300px;
height:150px;
transform:scale(0.3);
transition:all 3s ease;
}
.main:hover{
background:red;
transform:scale(1.);
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<div class="main"></div>
```

Кстати я немножко покопался и выяснил одну интересную вещь:
Если убрать со страницы все инпуты то hover эффект перестанет срабатывать по загрузке страницы. С чем связана эта зависимость?

P.S Чтобы воспроизвести проблему скопируйте код на локальную машину (на сторонних сайтах это не получается сделать из-за скриптов)

Answer (score 3):

Как оказалось есть такой [баг](https://lab.laukstein.com/bug/input) в Google Chrome связанный на input и form.
Решение как оказывается не сложное и нужно написать после всех стилей такой код:

`<script> </script>` ***пробел между тегами не случаен!***

Comment: Т.е. после всех стилей? Объясните пожалуйста. В конце html страницы вы имеете в виду? перед закрывающим тегом `<script> </script></body>`.

Comment: Насколько я помню когда я это тестировал, у меня стили были объявлены в теге head и там же этот специальный script.
Должно работать в любом случае даже и как вы сказали, но я имел ввиду после всех стилей буквально, вот прямо после всех.
P.S Это касается html страниц не имеющих скриптов вообще

Comment: Всё понял спасибо! Мне так-же помогла эта статья: https://css-tricks.com/transitions-only-after-page-load/

Comment: Интересно, но ее функциональность ровно такая же как и пустого скрипта. Смысл в том чтобы вообще был какой-то скрипт. А то что там добавляется и удаляется класс дело десятое

Comment: А я так-же отвечал на вопрос кому-то, тот через JS создавал новый iframe там стили дёргались при загрузке у него.. Я ему скинул про то, что нужно скрипт создать и вот эту запись со цсс-трикс, он сказал, что запись с цсс-трикс помогла, я уж не стал расспрашивать почему джава скрипт в конце дома не помог. Код не мой и дела не мои )